# Am I correct in saying that $P(\{a\}) = \{\{a\}, \emptyset\}$, $P(P(\{a\})) = \{\{\{a\}\}, \{a\}, \emptyset, \{\{a\},\emptyset\}\}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm getting a bit confused over the elements of repeated power sets of a singleton set. 
Could someone clarify the for me P({a}) through P(P(P(P({a})))) ? 
Thanks!

$$P(\{a\})=\{\{a\},\{\}\}$$
 $$P(P(\{a\}))= \{\{a\},\{\}\ , \{\{a\}\} ,\{\{a\},\{\}\} \} etc?$$

Comment: Edit your post to include what you think the power sets are. Also, I would encourage you to [look at this to typeset your mathematics](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex), or else your post will get very messy very quickly (hint: `$\mathcal{P}(\{a\})$` renders to $\mathcal{P}(\{a\})$).

Comment: The number of elements in $P\dots P(\{a\})$ will be $2^{\#P}$. So your last set will has $16$ elements.

Comment: The set containing only the empty set is missing from your second set, but the set $\{a\}$ isn't an element of $P(P(\{a\}))$.

Comment: how is {a} not a subset of P(P({a}))?

Comment: @123454321 Because $\{a\}$ is an *element* of $P(P(\{a\}))$, not a *subset*.

Comment: Oh i misread you, nevermind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\mathcal{P}(\{a\})=\{ \varnothing, \{a\}\}$$

$$\mathcal{P(\mathcal{P}(\{a\}))}=\mathcal{P}(\{ \varnothing, \{a\}\})=\{ \varnothing, \{ \varnothing, \{a\}\}, \{ \varnothing\}, \{ \{a \}\}\}$$

PS:If $A=\{a,b\}$ is a set, then:
$$\varnothing \in \mathcal{P}(A), \{a,b\} \in \mathcal{P}(A), \{a\}, \{b\} \in \mathcal{P}(A)$$

Comment: could you go on to do the 3rd and 4th please? this is quite helpful

Comment: Could you give it a try, in the same way as I did above? @123454321

Comment: Actually i've got it, I misread a comment above that said "The number of elements in $P…P({a})$ will be $2^{#P}$" thinking #P meant number of Ps, instead of the cardinality of the previous set

Comment: I think i'm happy now

Comment: Nice... ;) @123454321